# Pygame bliting scaled image

Tags: python, pygame

When i try to blit an image in pygame the image blits smaller than the actual image, my simplified code is

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1176,674),0,32)
background = pygame.image.load("picture.jpg").convert()

while True:
    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

The resulting image is about half the size it should be

Comment: could you post a link to your image?

Comment: helps to know you're under mac os x, could you post a link too to original jpg file? i can test it under other os.

Comment: On Linix Mint image is OK. But there is no guarantee that the server didn't convert the file and didn't remove some information and we now use little different image than you ;)

Comment: would running this in 64 bit make a difference to the outcome picture?

Comment: I've tested this on Win 7 with Python 2.7.5 and pygame 1.9.1release, it looks ok. So your problem is MAC OS X specific problem with pygame.

Comment: by the way check this thread out it isn't quite a duplicate but it should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228026/transforming-images-in-pygame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the issue came from my MacBooks retina screen resolution, once i downloaded a program to adjust the resolution the program worked properly

Answer (score 1):

It is entirely possible that when you view it you have zoomed in. Or there could be formatting irregularities. Either way, there are two simple solutions. Solution number 1 is to just scale up the image in an image editor, if you don't have one, GIMP is free online. A better way is to scale it in the code. You can just double the size of an image you loaded with this modification to your code, solving your problem. Use pygame.transform:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1176,674),0,32)
background = pygame.image.load("start_screen.jpg").convert()
background = pygame.transform.scale(background, (1176,674))

while True:
    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

this should work