# Screen size to image size

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to set the size of the screen to the size of the image that is uploaded. So far I have this:

```
 def backgroundImage(self, picture,x,y):
     picture=pygame.image.load(picture)
     picture=pygame.transform.scale(picture,(x,y))
     self.screen.blit(picture,(x,y))
```

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228026/transforming-images-in-pygame) post. But it doesn't seem to be working.

I however, I do want the user to be able to call a method which does this automatically, I know Java has a method in the Swing library called [pack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29) Is there a way to achieve this using Pygame?

I was thinking, getting the surface width and height and assigning this to the screen width and height, but this logic doesn't quite work is there a better option?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your function take a image and scale it use all the screen space. You want that the windows fit the size of the image, is that right?
So, you must use screen=pygame.display.set_mode([x,y])

Comment: the screen to adjust to the picture size, only if the user chooses to call the method which does this.

Comment: As @A.H said you must use set_mode(), keep in mind that it will return a new surface object so `self.screen = set_mode(...)`

Comment: What do you mean by saying "It doesn't seem to be working"?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have got the width and size of the image, but you are blitting the image outside of the screen. All you have to do is replace the x and y in the last line with two 0s.

> ```
>     def backgroundImage(self, picture,x,y):
>         picture=pygame.image.load(picture)
>         picture=pygame.transform.scale(picture,(x,y))
>         self.screen.blit(picture,(0,0))
> ```